# How to put log4j 2 configuration file on the classpath of encapsulated third-party framework using slf4j?

Tags: logging, eclipse-rcp, classpath, slf4j, log4j2

My Eclipse RCP application includes a plugin encapsulating a third-party framework. This framework, a pure OSGi system, uses *SLF4J*. My own application uses *log4j 2*, which works fine. The third-party framework seems to recognize "my" *log4j 2* fine, but triggers the usual `ERROR StatusLogger No log4j2 configuration file found. Using default configuration: logging only errors to the console.` message.

Adding the file *log4j2.xml* to the folder *src/main/resources* (yes, and adding it to the build) doesn't have any effect.

How can I provide the third-party framework's *SLF4J* instance with a config file? I don't think I can get access to its classpath, and I want to avoid setting the `log4j.configurationFile` system property. The latter mainly because I cannot figure out how to have it point to a folder relative to - say - my application home, a hint here might be just the solution I'm after. Setting the property to an absolute path works just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found a relatively simple solution while reconsidering setting the system property for the log4j 2 configuration file.

It works fine when I include the following in the `Activator`'s `start` method of my app entrance (core) plugin, i.e., set the system property programmatically where I have access to paths relative to my app launcher etc. Note that there are no issues with the core plugin's config file, only with the third-party framework's.

```java
// Configure log4j2 configuration file to be found
System.setProperty("log4j.configurationFile",
    getBundle().getResource("log4j2.xml").getPath());
```

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
String fileName = "config/log4j2.xml";
Configurator.initialize(null, fileName);
```

For SJLF,

https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-slf4j-impl/index.html

just include log4j-slf4j-impl-2.0.jar in class path

Comment: Thanks. I'm hesitant to use the `initialize` method though, as it isn't public API: *You could use the static method #initialize(String contextName, ClassLoader loader, String configLocation) (see source code) in org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Configurator. (You can pass null for the class loader.) Be aware that this class is not part of the public API so your code may break with any minor release.* ([log4j 2 FAQ](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/faq.html#config_from_code))